DeclareExerciseType/XSIMtransate doesn't appear like I expected?
This is my first time asking a question here because every question I've had over the past 20 years was already answered somewhere in here. So thank you all so much for that. I'm not ok with your wisdom being stolen and fed into AI, so I feel bad for asking here, but I'm also going nuts with this. I also didn't realize how terrifying this would be.
I'm trying to use the XSIM package and renaming 'exercise' to 'version'.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\DeclareExerciseType{vers}{
    exercise-env= vers,
    solution-env= versol,
    exercise-name= \XSIMtranslate{version} ,
    exercises-name= \XSIMtranslate{versions} ,
    solution-name= \XSIMtranslate{solution} ,
    solutions-name= \XSIMtranslate{solutions} ,
    exercise-template = default ,
    solution-template = default ,
    exercise-heading = \subsection*,
    solution-heading = \subsection*,
}
\begin{document}
This is text.
\begin{vers} 
    Here is a version.
\end{vers}

\begin{exercise}
    Here is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\end{document}


I've used overleaf.com and an app on my ipad to compile.
On overleaf I get :

“C ̇ ̇XSIM ̇KEYWORD ̇PREFIX ̇TL VERSION 1
Where I expect to see Version 1
And on my iPad app there just isn't a word before 1. I attached an imaged in case that's not clear.

I cleared my cached files on overleaf and that didn't change the output.


Welcome to TeX.SX. Nothing terrifying here! I think this might be a package bug, but I'm not sure yet...

Clearly @CFR knows more about this than I do. Still, the output you got was very strange; the lack of an error message might count as a bug. It may be worth reporting it here.

xsim doesn't know the word version or how to render it in the active (or any language), so you have to let it know how the term should be translated. For example,
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xsim}
\DeclareExerciseType{vers}{
  exercise-env= vers,
  solution-env= versol,
  exercise-name= \XSIMtranslate{version} ,
  exercises-name= \XSIMtranslate{versions} ,
  solution-name= \XSIMtranslate{solution} ,
  solutions-name= \XSIMtranslate{solutions} ,
  exercise-template = default ,
  solution-template = default ,
  exercise-heading = \subsection*,
  solution-heading = \subsection*,
}
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{version}{
  Fallback = version ,
  English = version ,
}
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{versions}{
  Fallback = versions ,
  English = versions ,
}
\begin{document}
This is text.
\begin{vers} 
  Here is a version.
\end{vers}

\begin{exercise}
  Here is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\end{document}

See page 48 for details and the following pages for a list of pre-defined terms.

Alternatively, you can just write version and versions and ditch the \XSIMtranslate for those words. If only you use it and you only use it in English, say, there's no advantage to using the translation framework.

Thank you, cfr! I've been making more of an effort to not copy and paste things without any understanding of how they work, but clearly not enough. Getting rid of XSIMtranslate worked perfectly and now I know what everything means!
May you never again get a telemarketing call.

@AliskaGibbins It was the translate which made me suspicious ;). Some packages use a translation framework to accommodate uses in different languages. It's a good idea, but it would be helpful if xsim's documentation pointed you to this in the section containing the sample code for defining a new type of exercise. That said, the documentation is good once you find the right bit.
